Binomial logistic regression and inter-group comparison
I am interested in exploring the relationship between two categorical variables: "Ethnicity" and "Disease", each with two levels. My primary hypothesis is that individuals with "Ethnicity A" are likely to exhibit "Disease". Additionally, I'd like to include "Age" as a confounding variable. My dataset also has three types of subjects: "Students", "Teachers", and "Managers". The main question is whether this association between "Ethnicity" and "Disease" is different in these three different types of subjects. For example, the association is "more powerful" in "Students" than "Teachers" and "Managers". What should I do for the statistical analysis? Should I use binomial logistic regression in each of these three groups, and compare the odds ratios? Is there any way of obtaining a "p-value" for the comparison?
